# Unrar local files to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, rar

I have two Linux servers, one which has several RAR files and another empty one. I would like to extract the archives and move the content to Server 2.

The problem is: I do not have enough storage to extract the files at Server 1. Also I cannot use SSHFS, as no FUSE modules can be loaded on Server 1.

I have seen that `unrar` has the `p` option which sends the output to STDOUT. Is it somehow possible to use this to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have enough space on server 2 to move/copy the files over there *and* extract them afterwards?

Comment: In addition to @SvW 's suggestion, do you have enough space to extract the files from one (or some) of the archives?  Is there any reason you can't do this in stages, instead of extracting everything all at once?

Answer (score 1):

While I suppose that the `unrar p` command may be theoretically usable it would cause all of the files in the archive to be printed one after the other in the same stream which would leave you to solve how to parse this and separate it into different files again.

As the goal seems to be to avoid storing the archives on the destination host before extracting them it would probably have made sense to stream the archive across as-is and do the extraction locally at the destination, where the extracted files can be written separately.
However, while this approach would work fine for eg a `.tar.gz`, a `.cpio.gz` or whatnot, **in the case of a `.rar` archive this does not work as the format is not streamable** (seeking is required).

I believe your best option, as was suggested in the comments to the question, is to copy the archives across and then extract them (possibly one at a time). If this is something that you will be doing repeatedly you may want to consider switching to a more suitable archive format.

Comment: +1 for not using rar. It's a wholly inappropriate format for professional use, mainly for this reason.